# Hölder's inequality/Cauchy-Schwarz for Bregman Divergence?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, metric-spaces, convex-optimization, machine-learning

Consider the [Bregman divergence.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bregman_divergence) 
$$
D_F(p, q) = F(p)-F(q)-\langle \nabla F(q), p-q\rangle.
$$
And its dual norm: 
$D_{F*}(p, q) $
where 
$
F^*(y) = \arg\min_x \left\{ \langle x, y\rangle - F(x) \right\}
$
based on the definition of [convex conjugacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate).

The Bregman divergence can be seen as a distance measure between its arguments. 
Can we say something like [Hölder's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) or perhaps using the Cauchy-Schwarz with Bregman Divergence? Something like this? 
$$
f(x) g(x) \leq D_{F^*}(f(x)||0). D_{F}(g(x)||0) 
$$

Here is a special case: If $F(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^\top x$, $D_R(x,y) = \frac{1}{2} \| x- y \|^2$. Similarly dual norm is also $\ell 2$, and Cauchy-Schwarz follows.

Comment: For this to be a viable inequality, you'd need $D_F$ and $D_{F^*}$ to scale linearly, which corresponds to $F$ being quadratic.

Comment: Good point. If F is strongly convex (equivalently F* is smooth) we should be able to get it. But still have not written it in a clean form.

Comment: The downvoting is getting ridiculous.

Comment: Paging the likely suspect in a separate comment, in case wrong.  @Sally